# PowerShell script to test passwords - $LASTEXITCODE

Tags: powershell, truecrypt

I have this code in PowerShell script:

```
$passwords = Get-Content "passwords.txt"
$TCPath = "c:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe"
$TCfile = "container.tc"
foreach ($password in $passwords)
{
    $LASTEXITCODE=99
    & $TCPath "/l z /s /q /p$password $TCfile"
    if ($LASTEXITCODE)
    {
        write-host YES
    }
    else
    {
        write-host NO
    }
}
```

$LASTEXITCODE is always 99 after the call to TCPath, so the script is always printing `YES`. Call to TC is not changing anything in $LASTEXITCODE. What should I do to get exit code from TrueCrypt?

Comment: What happens if you write `IF ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 99)`? If awaits a bool and tries to cast the value to a bool.

Comment: It confirms the condition.

Comment: I don't know what errorlevel truecrypt does return - but unless it is 0 you will always get a "Yes". Execute this line `-5 .. 5 |%{if ($_) {write-host "yes $_"} else {write-host "no  $_"} }`  to see what I mean.

Comment: TC returns 0 if command succeeded, higher value if not. This is possible with errorlevel in batch file, but it seems that not in PS script.

Comment: Aside from doubts about your objective for this scripts, you don't seem to understand that the if in your script simply returns the $true condition if $LASTEXITCODE is anything but `0`. To know what the value really is you have to `write-host "Yes $LASTEXTICODE and $?"` instead of only YES

Comment: `$LASTEXITCODE` is not changed upon the execution of TrueCrypt.

Comment: why are you setting the `$lastexitcode` to 99 manually? Is that what you're searching for? When the exitcode is 99, you want to do something? your `if` statement will now always be true because the `$lastexitcode` variable is not empty. you will achieve what you want when you delete `$lastexitcode = 99` and change your `if` to `if ($lastexitcode -eq '99')`

Comment: No, it will not work as you say. You don't understand the problem. Setting the variable should not make any difference. The problem is that TrueCrypt does not set this variable. In PowerShell this is not possible to do what I need. Batch file is the solution.

Comment: @SimonS I told exactly that in my very first comment

Comment: I don't see where you say it is impossible.

Comment: @pbies This problem is absolutely possible to solve using Powershell. I would start with removing `$LASTEXITCODE=99`. By having this line, `$LASTEXITCODE` is always true. Even if TrueCrypt doesn't affect `$LASTEXITCODE`, you could parse the output from each password tested for some known pattern in the success or failure.

Comment: TC does not provide any output. I can try to access the drive that will be attached, but this doesn't solve the problem that TC does not set both variables. Removing this line gives nothing. If you know the solution - post it as an answer. I mean solution that one of the variables is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution for correct retrieval of exit code from TC is to use Start-Process command.

```
$process = (Start-Process -FilePath "$TrueCrypt" -ArgumentList "/a /s /q /l z /m ro /v $container /p $password" -PassThru -Wait)
if ($process.ExitCode -eq 0)
{
    success($password)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after much research I can see that TrueCrypt can't set $LASTEXITCODE and the problem can't be resolved by $?. So the only way to test passwords is a batch file. One liner is enough:

```
@FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (passwords.txt) DO @"C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe" /a /s /l z /q /v container.tc /p "%%A" & echo %%A
```